# Building a computer: How do I figure out what is wrong with my system?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

I am trying to modernize a computer. I bought a new motherboard and a new processor (without integrated graphics) and kept the graphics card. After assembly of the computer, without attaching any hard drives and with minimal RAM only, the system appears to start, the motherboard control LEDs light up in the order CPU / RAM / VGA and finally BOOT (which stays on, since HDD are not connected).

However, the graphics card fans stop after ten or so seconds and no graphics output is either on the DVI or the HDMI output. The graphics card works correctly with the old motherboard and processor.

How do I check what is wrong? On paper, everything appears to be fine: the motherboard supports the processor, the graphics card is a standard PCIe graphics card. Processor, graphics card and the motherboard are not bottom shelf, processor and motherboard are new. RAM is supposed to be compatible as well. Power connectors appear all to be in place (with exception of the PWR2 processor connector, but unless I am mistaken that one is rarely needed). The powersupply is 700W and so exceeds the nominal power of the elements combined (processor 65W, motherboard – hard to say, but Google says its 250W under load, the graphics card not more than 100W).

(i) What is the correct way to proceed from this point?
(ii) Given that the CPU check of the motherboard seems to be positive, am I right in the assumption that this is not a processor related issue? (iii) I thought that one way of checking what element is problematic would be to buy a (cheap) graphic card just for the purpose of testing the system and seeing what the BIOS says. Would that make sense? (iv) am I correct in the assumption that, just as in the olden days, I should see *something* on the screen even with no memory or HDD connected?

Edit: I did make sure that the thermal paste is correctly distributed and I checked that the graphics card is compatible with the motherboard. I have checked the connectors several times. I have been following the ESD precautions except for wearing a wristband. I am a dinosaur, but these things have not changed much from my times...

Comment: Make sure thermal paste is correct.  Make sure the graphics card is compatible (carefully check documentation).  Test each device with the manufacturer's driver test app for that device.  Use memtest86.exe for memory. Recheck all connections.

Comment: How do I run memtest86.exe and / or use driver test apps if I don't see any graphical output?

Comment: Did you take proper `esd` precautions? Touching metal occasionally does not help.

Comment: Make a boot USB for Memtest86 with Rufus and try to boot with that.  If no, take the machine to a local repair shop

Comment: @Bib: yes, I did, except for wearing the wristband (I kept touching unisolated parts of the chassis).

Comment: @John: I thought that boot process takes place *after* the graphics has been initialized, am I wrong? How can inserting a boot USB help?

Comment: @January That is not taking proper `esd` precautions. All you need to do is move and the charge immediately starts to build up. It is possible that you have destroyed components. Before you touch anything else,go spend some money on proper equipment and learn how to use is. Youtube is full of info on this.

Comment: Like I said, try starting with the USB you created and if that fails take it to a repair shop

Comment: @Bib: it is [according to IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/coss/3.14.6?topic=installation-esd-precautions) and common practice. I am in software not hardware, but I did have some relevant training.

Comment: @John, sure, thank you, I will definitely try that, but I am not sure I can even select the right boot device if I can't see the screen. Am I wrong in thinking that graphics is initialized before the boot process? As for bringing it to the shop, sure, I could do that, or even buy a new computer, but where is the fun in that ;-)

Comment: Should work in VGA mode without bells and whistles

Comment: @January Rubbish. They expect you to _continually_ touch metal whilst handling components. Again, please go to youtube. There are plenty of companies whose function revolves around this.

Comment: I have never used a wristband in the 40 years I have been building machines all the way down to soldering boards and have yet to fry something.  Hundreds of builds and repairs.  Although *possible*, extremely unlikely.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas that is my experience as well. Basically, touching some grounded metal gets rid of statics and it does not build up very quickly. I have repaired laptops, I have assembled servers, and the last piece of hardware I fried in my life was a ZX Spectrum in 1990 (by pulling out an extension while live... I can't forgive myself to this very day). Also, some back story: this is the second time I try to assemble this computer, now with completely new parts. And the old components still work, no statics seems to have damaged them.

Comment: Go to https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClEm3nbu_3iURr8e9DRVwpA if you believe it is safe. Just because you _think_ there is no damage, does not mean to say there is none. Static builds up in less than 1 second.

Comment: Does the motherboard have a built in graphics card? You may have to connect to it long enough to get into the bios and then disable it.

Comment: @Larryc as far as I know the motherboard (MSI Z590 Pro A) requires a graphic controller. Would you recommend getting a cheap controller just to test things?

Comment: @Bib: fine, let us just assume that I fried something because I built up a static charge within a few seconds between grounding and manipulating the element. That still does not change my questions: how do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs that, here is how I have solved the problem.

First, I got an old graphics card and inserted it into the other PCI slot (PCI_E3) of the motherboard. It worked, demonstrating that both the CPU and the motherboard are all OK. Windows booted, everything was fine.

Then, I swapped the graphic cards. It turned out that now the old graphics card in the slot PCI_E1 no longer worked, but the 1050 ti in PCI_E3 worked.

Turns out that there is a fundamental difference between PCI_E1 and the other PCI slots on the Z560 motheboard. From the manual: PCI_E1: "PCIe 4.0/ 3.0 x16 (From CPU)"; PCI_E3: "PCI_E3: PCIe 3.0 x4 (From Z590 chipset)".

I have no idea why the PCI_E1 does not work, but the configuration with PCI_E3 works. The answer to my question is: try a different PCI slot.